# Ax2009 printing from AOS

Tags: printing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

How is it possible to hide printers that are locally installed on the AOS server for specific users for a AX client that is hosted using terminal services?

It still needs to be possible to print to the printers from the AOS while setting up print job settings in the code from AX client and all of the users, but certain users should not be able to see the printers, or a certain number of printers, in the print job settings dialog when it comes up.

Or, is it possible to define whether or not certain users have access to certain printers from the AOS?

Note: You can set in the client settings whether or not printers should be usable from the AOS, but if you are using terminal services for hosting the AX client, then all users are using the same configuration and therefore, if you want to set it so that one user can see the AOS printers, than all of the users are able to see the printers from the AOS. (Or I am mistaken here?)

Comment: Do users have access to print to this printer normally (and you don't want them using the AOS version), or is the printer specifically for AOS printing and nobody else has access to it?

Comment: @kingofzeal Users do have access to the printer to print through the AOS, but not all users should have access to the same printers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible make user security on printer from AX.

It may be possible using Windows security, but it might backfire if AX can see the printer but not use it.